# In XCode 4.3 how can I search other paths for frameworks and libraries to link to my project?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

I am using XCode 4.3.3 and want to include custom frameworks (in my case OCMock) into my Mac OS X project. I have put OCMock.framework (version 2.0) into `/Library/Frameworks` for now and when I open the build phases tab for my unit testing target that I want to link against OCMock I have the option to add the framework here:

[image: Link Frameworks]

When I click the + button I get presented with a search dialog that I can use to search for frameworks. `/Library/Frameworks` is not being searched for here.

[image: Search Frameworks]

It just searches the frameworks directory inside XCode.app and the Mac OS X 10.7 SDK which I am building the project with.

So how can I extend the search dialog with more locations, for example, `/Library/Frameworks` so that I can easily search for and include OCMock.framework?

Comment: Did you try the "Add Other" Button?

Comment: Yes it can certainly be found by selecting Add Other... But I was going for an easier search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't place the framework in system directories. Instead, drag it into the Project Navigator in Xcode, and tell Xcode to copy the files into the project folder. Once a framework has been added to the project's files, you can drag it from the navigator into the Link Binary With Libraries build phase.

Comment: So custom frameworks are encouraged to be packaged together with a project? Is the reason for this to ensure portability of the project?

Comment: I can't speak to why it was set up that way, but it is much better for portability.